# How to fill properties of class TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Lets assume there is a model class like:

```
class Filter implements IFilterJournal {
  public category: number;
  public subject: number;
  public teacher: number;
  public mark: number;
}
```

I can create instance of this class:

```
let f = new Filter();
```

It returns object `Filter` with empty properties inside.

How to fill properties of class more convenient?

I can determine consturctor like:

```
public constructor(public category: number, public subject: number, public teacher: number, public mark: number){
}
```

Then at the time of creation instance pass parameters:

```
let f = new Filter(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But what if I need to fill only `public subject: number;` property? either
 others? How to fill them selectively?

Another was is to make parameters as optional:

```
public constructor(public category?: number, public subject?: number, public teacher?: number, public mark?: number){}
```

Then use this like:

```
let f = new Filter(subject = 1);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you can initialize the object with any combination of properties, you can use a constructor that takes `Partial<Filter>` as an argument, and uses `Object.assign` to set the fields on the object.

```
class Filter  {
    constructor(data: Partial<Filter>){
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    public category: number;
    public subject: number;
    public teacher: number;
    public mark: number;
}
new Filter({ category: 0})
new Filter({ category: 1, subject: 2, teacher: 3, mark: 4})
```

**Note** `Partial` is a mapped type that keeps the members of a type but marks all of them as `Partial`. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). In this case `Partial<Filter>` is equivalent to:

```
interface PartialFilter{
    category?: number;
    subject?: number;
    teacher?: number;
    mark?: number;
}
```

---

If your type has methods, `Partial` would allow the argument to the constructor to contain those methods, this may be an issue. You can use conditional types to filter out methods from the argument, but it's a bit more complicated:

```
type NotFunctions<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P]  extends Function ? never : P }[keyof T];
class Filter  {
    constructor(data: Partial<Pick<Filter, NotFunctions<Filter>>>){
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    public category: number;
    public subject: number;
    public teacher: number;
    public mark: number;

    public sayHi(){ return "Hi" }
}
new Filter({ category: 0, sayHi: ()=> {}}) //Error with new constructor argument type 
new Filter({ category: 0})
new Filter({ category: 1, subject: 2, teacher: 3, mark: 4})
```

Comment: What is it: `Partial`?  In my case it is `interface IFilter {}` type

Comment: @OPV explained Partial a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Like C# class:

```
export class Filter {
    category: number = null;
    subject: string = null;
    teacher: number = null;
    mark: boolean = null;

public constructor(init?: Partial<Filter>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
}}
```

When you create a new instance all field names are disponible and empty.

```
const instance_of_filter: Filter = new Filter();
```

you have now a class with all fields defined :

```
instance_of_filter {
    "category": null,
    "subject": null,
    "teacher": null,
    "mark": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to fill all the object properties right off that bat.

```
public constructor(public _category: number){
    category = _category;
}
```

Would work just fine. Just keep in mind that those properties you don't fill will be undefined if you call them later before assigning them, so at the very least you may want to initialize them to some sort of acceptable value. Perhaps:

```
public constructor(public _category: number){
    this.category = _category;
    this.subject = 0;
    this.teacher = 0;
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: I dont want to write `set/get` for each properties.

Comment: Something like this?

     `new Filter({catagory: 5, subject: 4})`

Answer (score 1):

Here's base solution :

```
class Filter implements IFilterJournal {

  public subject: number;

  // Define defaults 
  // Not need to complicate with constructor 
  private category: number = 0;
  private teacher: number = 0;
  private mark: number = 0;

  public constructor(subject: number) {

    if (typeof subject === 'number') {
      this.subject = subject;
    } else {
      console.error('Class error: Constructor parameter subject is not a number!');
    }

  }

  // Define setters
  public setCategory(category: number) {
    this.category = category;
  }

  public setTeacher(teacher: number) {
    this.teacher = teacher;
  }

  public setMark(mark: number) {
    this.mark = mark;
  }

  // Define getters
  public getCategory(): number {
    return this.subject;
  }

  public getTeacher(): number {
    return this.teacher;
  }

  public getMark(): number {
    return this.mark;
  }

  public getSubject(): number {
    return this.subject;
  }

}
```